# How to install Java plugin for browser solely?

Tags: browser-addons, java-applet

I am using java SDK on my PC without running the installation file. That is I manually added environment variables which is good enough for me.

My question is how can I install Java plugin for browser to view applet without installing the whole java SDK or JRE?

Comment: [jPortable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable) does this for Firefox Portable/Chrome Portable/[any_program_name_here] Portable. You can try to reverse engineer what it exactly does.